# Cannot start app on WebLogicServer 10mp1

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Cannot start my app I have added.
It is in prepared state and if I try to start it, nothing happens.
It is a new local server that installed today.
If a check the logs, it say's -

```
####<2013-mar-14 kl 10:53 CET> <Warning> <netuix> <1> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <1363254820815> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=WebAppApplicationOverviewPage&WebAppApplicationOverviewPortlethandle=com.bea.console.handles.AppDeploymentHandle%28%22com.bea%3AName%3DCMGWebTool%2CType%3DAppDeployment%22%29.>

####<2013-mar-14 kl 13:19 CET> <Warning> <netuix> <1> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <1363263546931> <BEA-423420> <Redirect is executed in begin or refresh action. Redirect url is /console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=HomePage1.>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The log you posted is just warning. Any error in the log? I mean all the log -- server log, stdout, stderr, domain log, etc

Comment: Not what I can find. I will continue looking. Any ideas?

Comment: Have looked throw the logs and it doesn't give any errors. Tried with a app that works on another weblogic server 10mp1 and does not work.

Comment: Solved it. Added a listen adress, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Added a listen adress, and it worked.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Where did you add listen address?